# Оптимизировать решение задачи на зависимости

Tags: python, олимпиада, зависимости

Условие: Автор Р. пишет серию книг, состоящую из N томов, на довольно популярную тему. Так как автор этот не отличается особым талантом и красноречием, а тема уже давно себя исчерпала, то неудивительно, что информация может повторяться, перетекая из одного тома в другой. Но автор, будучи не совсем уж глупым, решил сам обратить на этот казус внимание своих читателей, при каждом повторе информации указывая, на какую из уже написанных книг он сослался. Итак, наша задача - выяснить, с какой вероятностью информация из каждой книги будет вами прочитана, возьми вы одну наугад.

Формат ввода: В первой строке входного файла вводится число N - количество томов в серии, и число  M - количество «зависимостей» одной книги от другой.
В следующих M строках вводятся пары чисел A, B - существование «зависимости» книги под номером A от книги под номером B. Если читатель прочитает книгу A, то автоматически узнает информацию из книги B, так как автор на неё ссылается.
Гарантируется, что не существует книг, взаимно ссылающихся друг на друга.

Формат вывода:
В N строках выведите вещественные числа X(i) с точностью не менее 6-ти знаков после запятой, где X(i) - вероятность (в процентах), что информация из этой книги попадётся читателю, возьми он любую книгу наугад.

Пример:
Ввод:

4 3

4 3

3 1

2 1

Вывод:

100.0000000

25.0000000

50.0000000

25.0000000

Мои рассуждения: Я считываю все пары чисел, создавая словарь, где ключ - номер книги B, а значение - пополняющееся в течение цикла множество книг A, которые зависят от B.
Собрав словарь, я ещё раз по нему пробегаюсь - у каждого ключа прохожу по множеству зависимых книг и проверяю, есть ли среди зависимых книг такие, которые сами являются ключами словаря (т.е. книги, от которых тоже есть зависимые рукописи). Цель цикла - подобрать во множество книги, зависящие от тех книг, которые сами являются зависимыми. Например, если у нас картина {1: {3}, 3: {2, 4}}, то от книги 1 зависит книга 3, от которой, в свою очередь, зависят книги 2 и 4. Т.о. автоматически от книги 1 зависят книги 3, 2 и 4; словарь принимает вид {1: {3, 2, 4}, 3: {2, 4}}. Пробежавшись, выношу вердикт - иду циклом i от 1 до N и смотрю - если i есть среди ключей словаря, значит, от этой книги зависит ещё хотя бы одна. В таком случае вероятность считаю равной (len(множество зависимых книг) + 1) / N (к длине единицу добавил, чтобы посчитать эту книгу тоже - имеется ввиду, что книга автоматически зависит сама от себя).
Если же i нет в ключах словаря, это значит, что от этой книги никакая другая не зависит, т.е. вероятность прочитать информацию из него равна 1 / N.
Вот, собственно, моё решение:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
term = {}
for i in range(m):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    if b not in term:
        term[b] = {a}
    else:
        term[b].add(a)
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    if i in term.keys():
        for j in term[i]:
            if j in term.keys():
                term[i] = term[i].union(term[j])
        print(format((len(term[i]) + 1) / n * 100, '.6f'))
    else:
        print(format(1 / n * 100, '.6f'))
```

Проблема в том, что такое решение не заходит в тестирующую систему (неверный ответ), кроме того, решение очень топорное, запутанное и требующее много времени для компиляции (из-за нескольких циклов сразу), но как его оптимизировать, я не знаю. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобными задачами на зависимости, буду очень рад узнать другие способы решения.

Answer (score 0):

Строим граф (DAG).

Из каждого узла запускаем поиск в ширину или глубину, обходя дерево доступности (может, есть какой-то спецтермин).

При посещении каждого узла для него увеличиваем счётчик деревьев, к которым он принадлежит.

Выводим `TreeCounter[i] / N`